# How can I properly call a JFrame from a class?

Tags: java, database, swing, class, jframe

I'm trying to instantiate a JFrame instance, but every time I reference the class, a new JFrame shows up.

The goal of my code is to select an option from the menu bar, and my database template/table will then show up on the frame, in which it does, but also creates two more JFrame's in the process, and I believe I have located the problem; I just don't know how to workaround said problem.

As above, every time I want to reference my JFrame class to add a template to my frame, it creates an extra JFrame because of the way my class is set up, how can I better my code so that this does not happen?

Here's my code:

The `tigerActionPerformed()` method is called when I select an item from my menu bar on my JFrame.

```
public class MenuActionListener implements ActionListener {

    public void tigerActionPerformed() {

        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.getDatabasePanel();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        switch (command) {

            case "tiger":
                tigerActionPerformed();
                break;

            default:
        }
    }
}
```

The frame class is then called to add my database to the JFrame.

```
public class MyFrame{

    private JFrame frame;

    public MyFrame() {

        MenuBar menuBarInstance = new MenuBar();

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Stock Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(720, 480));
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBarInstance.getMenuBar());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void getDatabasePanel() {

        //Add database test
        acp.addDatabaseTemplate(frame);

    }

}
```

This class adds my database template to my panel, and the panel is added to the JFrame.

```
public class AddComponentsToPane {

    public void addDatabaseTemplate(Container pane) {

        //We need to have a new class to fill the database table
        StockApplication stockApp = new StockApplication();

        JTable tigerTable = new JTable();
        tigerTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(0, 3));

        stockApp.FillTable(tigerTable, "SELECT * FROM TIGER_INFO");

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        //We need center panel to add a JTable
        //centerPanel.add(tigerTable, new GridBagConstraints());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        centerPanel.add(tigerTable, c);

        pane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

}
```

Comment: we are missing the important code lines like the method `addDatabaseTemplate()`. also you should make your class extend `JFrame` instead of creating a new one like you do it

Comment: well, with each new instance of `MyFrame` your constructor will open up another JFrame, as it´s what you´re doing in there. You might want to seperate this into another `show` method, and store this instance of `MyFrame` somewhere to reuse it at some later point and show the actual new JFrame. And if i understand it correctly the workflow here creates 2-3 instances of the `MyFrame` class.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have edited my post to include my database class.

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy yes, that's what I have gathered from my code too. I'm just not sure how to reference my JFrame class so that I stop creating instances of a new JFrame.

Comment: `tigerActionPerformed()` is killing it. every time its called, a new frame will be generated. to remove this problem, do the `MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();` **before** the method call in your code. show us the whole code for the class which includes the `tigerActionPerformed()` method

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have displayed all that is inside the `tigerActionPerformed()` class. When I select a menu item from my menu bar, this is the method that gets called. This method then calls my frame class in order to add the database panel to my JFrame.

Comment: post it as 1 code block so its easier to understand. `tigerActionPerformed()` is a method and not a class, so post every class as 1 block

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have edited my code to make it seem more clearer as to what I'm trying to do. Let me know what you think.

Comment: that can't be your whole code. please post **everything** otherwise its hard to make a working code out of it. we need especially the code where you add `MenuActionListener` to your menu and also your menu code

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new JFrame() each time `getDatabasePanel()` is called.

```
MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
frame.getDatabasePanel();
```

You don't need to do this since you've already created the JFrame `frame` at the top of your code.

Comment: I need to instantiate the frame class so I can essentially add my database template to the panel, which in turn gets displayed on my frame.

Comment: This code is in a different class, so I need to make a new instance of my frame class.

Comment: You can pass a reference to the frame to the other class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stuck and I'm not sure how I should be doing that.

Comment: In the constructor whichever class contains `tigerActionPerformed()`, pass in the JFrame as a parameter.

Comment: I am getting a NullPointerException when I put `MyFrame frame = new MyFrame` inside the classes constructor. Hence why I have it inside the method.

Comment: No, you need to pass it as a parameter to the constructor, not create a new one.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean, however, I'm not sure how I should be going about this. Do you have a code example I could use so I can create a reference off?